# The term 'New-RemoteMailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, email-server, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365

Trying to create the new remote mailbox for O365 (on-premis mailox does not exists).

I'm establishing connection to local Exchange server (either by EMS or by Invoke-Command PowerShell) and try to execute New-RemoteMailbox command. After this I'm getting error:

*The term 'New-RemoteMailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...*

Have someone faced such problem? That is strange as well as I using EMS that needs to have all cmdlets..

Comment: Did you establish a connection to the Office 365 tenant account in powershell prior to trying the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user running that command needs to be assigned to the Mailbox Import/Export role.  If you are not part of that role you will get the above message.

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role "Mailbox Import Export" –User <domain\user>
```